# how to get html source in windows 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-8

In windows 8, I try to get html source from URL:

```
private void loadingDatafromWeb(string URL)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
    request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReadCallbackLoadingData),request);
}
```

and:

```
private void ReadCallbackLoadingData(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    string myPageSource;
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
    HttpWebResponse response =   (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
    using (StreamReader myWebSource = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        myPageSource = myWebSource.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

I want to get string myPageSource in function loadingDatafromWeb, but i can't do it. Please tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new .Net 4.5 feature and call with `await` keyword:

```
private void loadingDatafromWeb(string URL)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
    string html = await ReadData(new Uri(request));
}
```

And your helper method is:

```
private async Task<string> ReadData(Uri uri)
{
     string result;

     // Get your response synchronously (do not forget to enscope WebResponse
     // and other Streams inside 'usings').

     return result;
}
```